# Selecting key and value of dictionary in Azure DocumentDB / Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Consider these two sample documents stored in DocumentDB.

**Document 1**

```
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817602",
"JobType": 3,
"
"Properties": {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2"
  }
"KeyNames": ["Key1", "Key2"]
```

**Document 2**

```
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817603",
"JobType": 4,
"
"Properties": {
    "Key3": "Value3",
    "Key4": "Value4"
  }
"KeyNames": ["Key3", "Key4"]
```

I want to select the all the keys and all the values in Properties object for each document.
Something like:

```
SELECT 
c.JobId,
c.JobType,
c.Properties.<Keys> AS Keys,
c.Properties.<Values> AS Values
FROM c
```

But as you can see the keys are not fixed. So how do I list them? So finally I get a result like this. I cannot use .NET or LINQ. I need a query to be executed in the DocumentDB Query Explorer.

```
[
{
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817602",
"JobType": 3,
"Key1": "Value1"
}

{
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817602",
"JobType": 3,
"Key2": "Value2"
}

{
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817603",
"JobType": 4,
"Key3": "Value3"
}

{
"JobId": "04e63d1d-2af1-42af-a349-810f55817603",
"JobType": 4,
"Key4": "Value4"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using UDF in DocumentDB. Since KeyNames is an array. Self-join was returning the key.

So this query.

```
SELECT 
c.JobId,
c.JobType,
Key,
udf.GetValueUsingKey(c.Properties, Key) AS Value
FROM collection AS c
JOIN Key in c.KeyNames
```

returned me the desired result.

You can define UDF by using Script Explorer provided in DocumentDB.
For my purpose I used:

```
function GetValueUsingKey(Properties, Key) { 
   var result = Properties[Key];
   return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Hope this helps :)